# iCloud uploading/sync images, videos and plist files

Tags: ios, swift, file-upload, icloud, cloudkit

I want to **upload Images, Videos and some PList files on iCloud** on Button Click event. I did following code but there are some issues.

(Q.1) It takes too much time to upload data on **iCloud Dashboard**  http://icloud.developer.apple.com/dashboard/.

(Q.2) Sometime Dashboard shows data and sometimes not.

(Q.3) One important question: right now its data shows in **iCloud Dashboard**, after app go live **will it be visible to user's iCloud drive?** because I need to this: data will visible to user's iCloud drive in a folder.

(Q.4) As I want to upload images, video and plist files, so my following *coding approach is correct or not?* else I need to use Key-Value storage or iCloud-Document upload or iCloud Drive upload? (right now i am using iCloud Drive upload method)

Below is my code:

```
private let pathsForDocDir = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSSearchPathDirectory.DocumentDirectory, NSSearchPathDomainMask.UserDomainMask, true)
let DOCUMENT_DIRECTORY: AnyObject = pathsForDocDir[0]
let filePath = DOCUMENT_DIRECTORY.stringByAppendingPathComponent("image1.png")

let File : CKAsset?  = CKAsset(fileURL: NSURL(fileURLWithPath: filePath))
let newRecord:CKRecord = CKRecord(recordType: "album")
newRecord.setValue(File, forKey: "ImageOrVideo")

let privateDB = CKContainer.defaultContainer().privateCloudDatabase
privateDB.saveRecord(newRecord) { (record : CKRecord?, error : NSError?) in
         if error != nil {
             print(error?.localizedDescription)
         } else {
             dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                 print("finished")
             }
         }
}
```

I am using this code in For loop because I have multiple files to upload.

(Q.5) And also I need to click on "Add Record ID Query Index" on iCloud Dashboard. you can see the screenshot of iCloud Dashboard.

[image: iCloud Dashboard - iCloud drive upload]